# Couldn't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'tensorflow'. You can use `micropip.install(..., keep_going=True)` to get a list of all packages

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pyscript

I want to use tensorflow in pyscript but it always throws this error. Please help me out.

```
    <py-env>
    - numpy
    - tensorflow
    - nltk
    </py-env>
    <body>
    <py-script>
        import random
        import json
        import pickle
        import numpy as np
        import nltk
        from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
        
        intents = json.loads(open("./intents.json").read())
        import tensorflow as tf
        
        keras = tf.keras
        from keras.models import load_model
        //further code..
    </py-script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyScript can't run anything that has a C component to be compiled.  That's why the error refers to a "pure Python" wheel.  Bottom line, you can't use `tensorflow` in a browser.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to use tensorflow in browser?

Comment: Sure, send the data to your server and do the processing there, where you have more power and you know whether or not there is a GPU.  PyScript is for lightweight processing.  You don't really want to burden the user's computer with that much processing.  And your open of `"intents.json"` is not going to work; PyScript code can't access the local file system.

Comment: Or use tensorflow.js https://www.tensorflow.org/js

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your great answers! Really appreciable.

Comment: As for alternatives in the browser, you can to the [MyBinder Gallery for launches at Gesis here](https://notebooks.gesis.org/gallery/mybinder/7d/) and search 'tensorflow' in the search bar on the right side. You'll see 'The-Applied-TensorFlow-and-Keras-Workshop' entry listed if you press the `launch binder` button on the right you'll get a session where you can import tensorflow in a notebook.  The sessions are temporary and has limited computational power, and so you'll need to check what you can work through of what you wanted.

Comment: That doesn't really help at all, does it?  If he wanted to run this for himself, he's do it from a command line.  He's trying to use TF as part of a web site offering.

Comment: I forgot to comment, that in the specific OP use case, my suggestion doesn't help, however, because of your phrasing "tensorflow in a browser" in this answer, others seeking to share running something with tensorflow without having the end user install it on a local machine may end up here. And for some of them being able to run it using a temporary session served to their browser via the MyBinder service may suffice. For example, imagine demonstrating running through something that has low computational power needs with others via an active Jupyter notebook in a temporary session.